# How to import or access UITextField from another Class

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols, subclass

I have Outlet of UITextField in the main VC and I want to access its text from another class... for more clarification please see my code below:

```
class ProductManagement : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var ProductName: UITextField!

}
```

and I want to read the text in below class

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class XUpload {
    
    
    static func UploadImage(Image : UIImage, Completion : @escaping (_ url : String)->()) {
        
        guard let imageData = Image.pngData()  else { return }
                let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        let pathRef = storage.child("Images/Products")
        
        let imageRef = pathRef.child(   // I want the product name to be written here!  )
        

            imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (meta, error) in
            imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                print (url as Any)
                                                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

I tried to create a custom protocol to delegate the UITextField but the problem is I couldn't conform it inside XUpload class !!

Please someone write for me how is my code should be because I'm beginner and new to Swift language.

Thank you in advance.

### EDIT:

**Elia Answer applied below:**

**ProductManagement Class + Extension**

```
    class ProductManagement : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        
            self.ProductName.delegate = self
    }
    
    
        @IBOutlet weak var ProductName: UITextField!
        @objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .PnameInputText, object: nil, userInfo: ["text": sender.text!])
        }
    
    
    }


extension Notification.Name {
    public static var PnameInputText = Notification.Name("PnameInputText")
}
```

**XUpload Class**

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class XUpload {
    
    private init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handle(_:)), name: .PnameInputText, object: nil)
    }
    
    public static var shared = XUpload()
    
    var textFieldText : String = "" {
        didSet {print("updated value > ", textFieldText)}
    }
    

    @objc private func handle(_ sender: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = sender.userInfo as NSDictionary?, let text = userInfo["text"] as? String {
        textFieldText = text
        }
    }
        
    
    
    
    static func UploadImage(Image : UIImage, Completion : @escaping (_ url : String)->()) {
        
        guard let imageData = Image.pngData()  else { return }
        
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        let pathRef = storage.child("Images/Products")
        let imageRef = pathRef.child("img_"+shared.textFieldText)
        print("var of textFieldText value: " + shared.textFieldText)  //print nothing... empty value!!
        
                
        imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (meta, error) in
            imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                print ("Image uploaded to this link >> " + url!.description)
                guard let str = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                Completion (str)
            }
        }
    }
    
}



extension UIImage {
    
    func upload(completion : @escaping (_ url : String) ->()) {
        XUpload.UploadImage(Image: self) { (ImageURL) in completion (ImageURL)
                        
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no value given to var textFieldText by the Notification Center!  why??

Comment: Where do you want to access the text field from?

Comment: @luckystars in the XUpload class inside the (static func UploadImage)... thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ProductManagement : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    var productInputText: String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var ProductName: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        ProductName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
         productInputText = sender.text ?? ""
    }

}
```

This will store your input text into a variable basically with listen edit changes.

And if I get not wrong, you use `UploadImage` within `ProductManagement` class. Add a function property to `UploadImage` as below

```
class XUpload {
    
    
    static func UploadImage(Image : UIImage, productName: String,  Completion : @escaping (_ url : String)->()) {
        
        guard let imageData = Image.pngData()  else { return }
                let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        let pathRef = storage.child("Images/Products")
        
        let imageRef = pathRef.child(   // I want the product name to be written here!  )
        

            imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (meta, error) in
            imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                print (url as Any)
                                                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

and call it in `ProductManagement` class like below.

```
XUpload.UploadImage(image: myImage, productName: productInputText, Completion: { 

}
```

EDIT:

After getting your comment, I decided the best way do it is using `Notification`, you use `UITextField` in ProductManagement class so there is no need to handle `delegate` method of them in `XUpload`

Describe notification name

```
extension Notification.Name {
    public static var TextChange = Notification.Name("TextChange")
}
```

In `ProductManagement`, `textDidChange` method post text to `Notification`

```
@objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .TextChange, object: nil, userInfo: ["text": sender.text])
    }
```

I convert your `XUpload` class to a `Singleton` class.

```
class XUpload {
    
    private init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handle(_:)), name: .TextChange, object: nil)
    }
    
    public static var Shared = XUpload()

    @objc private func handle(_ sender: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = sender.userInfo as NSDictionary?, let text = userInfo["text"] as? String {
            textFieldText = text
        }
        
    }
    
    var textFieldText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print("updated value > " , textFieldText)
        }
    }
    
    static func uploadImage() {
        // use updated textfield text with textFieldText
    }
    
    
}
```

Then store a variable in `ProductManagement` class as a singleton object and it wil work for you. The text in textfield updated every changes in `XUpload` class.

```
class ProductManagement : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
   var staticVariable = XUpload.Shared
}
```

Comment: No I want to implement an extension of UIImage inside Upload Class to upload the image then call it in ProductManagement .... ( That's why I want to bring the UITextField input to XUPload class.... now tell me how to call var productInputText in XUpload class please? I did write addTarget code but honestly I don't know how to call it in XUpload class... I already mentioned for you in the XUpload class where I want to put the UITextFiled input as a remark kindly check my comment inside the class and amend your answer please

Comment: Hey @Let.Simoo I edited at the end of my answer. It will work for you and I describe why you should notification but no delegate in your XUpload class. Hope you worked for you

Comment: dear @elia thank you for updating your answer... I followed your method step by step... and to make it much clear I've copied the whole code after I implemented your instructions but unfortunately I didn't get what I want :(

Comment: Edit your answer and copy paste all code what you tried, I will fix it as I write in my edit

Comment: done already before you reply.....pls have a look to the edit section in the bottom of my question

Comment: hey @Let.Simoo you forgot to addTarget for UITextField, please add it and give a try

Comment: I added...    var staticVariable = XUpload.shared
and I didn't get any print inside the updated value of var textFiledText
I call the textFieldtext variable inside (static func UploadImage) in both way
1-shared.textFieldText, 
2-XUpload.textFieldText
and both not worked (BTW which call is correct ??)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217722/discussion-between-let-simoo-and-elia).